# ArrayList calling method

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import acm.program.*;
import java.util.*;


public class ReverseArrayList extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {
        println("This program reverses the elements in an ArrayList.");
        println("Use 0 to signal the end of the list.");
        ArrayList<Integer> list = readArrayList();
        reverseArrayList(list);
        printArrayList(list);
    }

/* Reads the data into the list */
    private ArrayList<Integer> readArrayList() {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (true) {
            int value = readInt(" ? ");
            if (value == 0) break;
            list.add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I dont understand the following code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = readArrayList();
```

I dont understand why I can't do the following instead:

```
list.getInput();
```

Why do i need to make the ArrayList equal to the method, and this confuses me because now I'm unsure which way is needed whenever I want to call a method in java

Comment: `"I have a method that takes in an ArrayList..."` ? no, that method takes in nothing and **returns** an ArrayList. Your question seems very confused -- please clarify. It almost sounds as if you should read a basic tutorial on methods, how to call them, how to pass data into them, how to get information from them.

Comment: [edit] the text of your question please

Comment: And calling your own method **on** an ArrayList is not valid Java, since the method *returns* an ArrayList, but has not be defined for the ArrayList class. The only methods available for an ArrayList are as outlined in the Javadocs as per @AniketSahrawat's comment. Again, read the tutorials and learn the basics. They won't steer you wrong.

Comment: You can start with https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/Java/Java%20for%20Dummies%20%286th%20ed.%29%20%5BBurd%202014-03-31%5D.pdf

Comment: I uploaded my full code (involving my confusion), please take a look at it, sorry for the confusion, I'm still new in java.

Comment: `list` is an `ArrayList`, right? Do the JavaDocs (as given by @AniketSahrawat above) have a method `getInput()` for the ArrayList class? No. This is a method that you yourself have created for your own class, and you can only call that method on instances of your own class. This is fundamental Java, and it would behoove you to study the intro to Java tutorials.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat please see my edit, you dont have to be so quick to judge

Comment: Now your edit makes sense. You can not do `list.readArrayList()` because `list` is an instance of `ArrayList<String>` and `readArrayList()` belongs to `ReverseArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that the method `getInput()` does not take in an *ArrayList* as argument, but returning it instead. So it is reasonable that

```
Arrlist=getInput()
```

Is the correct syntax, you are assigning the returned *ArrayList* from `getInput()` to `Arrlist`. While on the other hand,

```
Arrlist.getInput()
```

represents a method that must be implemented in *ArrayList Class* or one of its superclasses, which is not true in your case. I would recommend revising *OOP* concepts.

Answer (score 0):

One way you might be able to pass it is using a constructor. I mocked up working code that does the same.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ArrayListExample {

  ArrayList<Integer> ofNumbers;

  public ArrayListExample() {
     ofNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
     createArray();

  }

  private void createArray(){
      ofNumbers = IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors
            .toCollection(ArrayList::new));
  }

  public ArrayList<Integer> getInput() {

    return ofNumbers;
  }

 public void getArray() {

    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(ofNumbers);

    for (Integer num : newList) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }

  }
}
```

I also agree with Andrew. Keep it up, with a little more practice this will become second nature to you.